# Create environment variable in WIX installer using the set /P cmd command

Tags: batch-file, wix, batch-processing, wix3.11

I have a window installer XML (WIX) installer.
I'm trying to create environment variable by using "set /P" cmd command in WIX as following:

```
<SetProperty Id="InstallationPathProf2019"
                Value="&quot;[SystemFolder]cmd.exe&quot; /C set /P TESTPATH=&lt;[TempFolder]fileA.txt"
                  Before="InstallationPathProf2019" Sequence="execute" >NOT REMOVE="ALL"</SetProperty>
<CustomAction Id="InstallationPathProf2019" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no"/>


<InstallExecuteSequence>
   <Custom Action="InstallationPathProf2019" After="InstallInitialize">NOT REMOVE="ALL"</Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

unfortunately the TESTPATH environment variable is not created after running the installer.
Can you please advise why is that happening?

p.s.
when perform the same directly in cmd, it works and TESTPATH environment variable is created:
[command line in CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wI5eT.png)

I hope someone can help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is there some reason  you aren't using native Windows Installer /  WiX capabilities for this? https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/environment.html

Comment: Thank you Christopher!
Yes , there is a reason why I can't use the native WIX capabilities.
I need first to find out the value of the environment variable by running vsWhere.exe utility, and write its' output to file, and only then create the environment variable with the founded value.
I'm don't familiar with a built in WIX capability that creates an environment variable from value written in a file.
Thanks again!!

Comment: WiX has a VS extension that has properties that tell you the installation directories of visual studio.  https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/customactions/wixvsextension.html#vs2019properties   You can use these in the Environment element to avoid a custom action.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use setx to create environment variable instead of set.

In your case, the command should probably look like this:

```
setx TESTPATH "[TempFolder]fileA.txt"
```

More information about setx can be found at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx